# Compressing an array when converting from SimpeXML

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

I have the following XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phonebooks>
    <phonebook owner="0" name="phonebook">
        <contact>
            <person>
                <realName>Name, Firstname</realName>
            </person>
            <telephony>
                <number type="mobile" vanity="CRUSH" quickdial="7" prio="1">01751234567</number>
                <number type="work" vanity="" prio="0">02239876543</number>
                <number type="fax_work" vanity="" prio="0">02239876599</number>
            </telephony>
        <contact>
            ...
        </contact>
        ...
    </phonebook>
</phonebooks>
```

My attempts with the following code...

```
foreach ($xml->phonebook->contact as $contact) {
    foreach ($contact->telephony->number as $number) {
        $attributes[(string)$number] = json_decode(json_encode((array) $number->attributes()), 1);
    }
}
```

provides me with a useful result:

```
Array
(
    [01751234567] => Array
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [type] => mobile
                    [quickdial] => 7
                    [vanity] => CRUSH
                    [prio] => 1
                )
        )
     ...
)
```

... but I would like it in the simpler structure.
Does anyone have an indication for me how to easily eliminate the unnecessary structural level [@attributes]?
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than converting to JSON and back:

```
json_decode(json_encode((array) $number->attributes()), 1)
```

Loop over the objects, and convert each to string directly:

```
$attributesForThisNumber = [];
foreach ( $number->attributes() as $attrName => $attrObj ) {
    $attributesForThisNumber[] = (string)$attrObj;
}
$attributes[(string)$number] = $attributesForThisNumber;
```

You can make this more compact (but not necessarily more readable) using:

- `iterator_to_array` to get a plain array of the objects `foreach` would be given (without the `@attributes` marker)
- `array_map` over that array in place of the `foreach`
- `strval()` for the string cast in place of `(string)`

Giving:

```
$attributes[(string)$number] = array_map('strval', iterator_to_array($number->attributes()));
```

Comment: Worked for me! Thx